# Grouping countries by regions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am creating an excel file for making a web analytics dashboard and my current problem is: How to group countries into different regions? Eg: EMEA, APAC, AMER

I have two excel files. The first one has columns: `account_id`, `external/internal`, and `country_list`.

The second file also contains a list of countries as well as their corresponding region (EMEA, APAC etc.) `countries`, `regions`

I would like to compare the  `country_list` column from file 1 with the `countries` column from file 2 and if the values match then the value in the regions column should be taken. For example: if  `country_list` and `countries` both contain "Germany", then the value should be EMEA.

So far I started as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

accounts = pd.read_excel('accountids_with_properties.xlsx', sheetname='accountids_with_properties')
CountryGroups = pd.read_excel('country_list.xlsx', sheetname='country_list')

def groupCountry(col):
    for col in accounts.index[3]:
        if col = CountryGroups.index[0]:
```

Answer (score 0):

`accounts.merge(CountryGroups, how='left', left_on='country_list', right_on='countries')`

If you are only interested in outputting country:region pairs, you can also do:

`CountryGroups[CountryGroups.countries.isin(set(accounts.country_list))]`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. I ended up reading in the country file as a list and then compared it to the bigger accounts file while also appending the regions into a new column into the accounts file.

The code looks like this:

```
#for index, row in df.iterrows():
#    print(row['c1'], row['c2'])
for index, row in accounts.iterrows():
    print(row['CountryGroups'])
    for index, entry in CountryGroups.iterrows():
        if row['accounts'] == entry['Country']:
            print(entry['Region'])
            row['Region'] = entry['Region']
            print(row)
            #return entry.index[1]
```